# Is every groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ uniquely represented by a group and cardinality of $\mathcal{G}_{Obj}$?

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

**Edit**: as user8268 noticed, what follows refers to connected groupoids only.
I have intuition, that while groupoids in general might have rich internal structure, all finite groupoids are "trivial" in precise sense: for each finite group $G$ and natural number n there is only one (up to iso) category that is groupoid with $n$ elements with homsets of these elements isomorphic to $G$. It seems analogous to ${\mathbb{T}1}$ topologies that in finite case are also necessarily trivial, i.e. discrete, or finite dimensional vector spaces, where choosing of underlying field and dimension uniquely determines space.

Is it true? If not, can you find contradiction in following reasoning?
Assume, that for category $C$ with $n$ objects there exists subcategory $S$ isomorphic to complete directed graph over $n$ elements. Such subcategory would necessarily contain exactly one morphism for each pair of objects. In particular identities for pair of equal objects. Such morphism is then iso both in $S$ and $C$. For convenience, lets call every subcategory with these properties a "web". My idea is that, whenever *web* exists for given $C$, not only each homset in $C$ is equinumerous, but *web* introduces "global equivalence" that permits to compose arbitrary morphisms (of $C$) regardless of their domain/codomain as follow:

let $S(A,B)$ be unique iso in web $S$ between $A,B\in C_{Obj}$. Then for $f,g\in C_{hom}$:
$f\sim_Sg \Leftrightarrow_{df} f=S(cod(g),cod(f))\circ g\circ S(dom(f),dom(g))$

composition $\bullet$ in quotient $C/\sim_S$:
$g_{\sim}\bullet f_{\sim}=(g\circ S(cod(f),dom(g))\circ f)_{\sim}$

I think that existence of web $S$ in $C$ implies$^1$ that $C$ is groupoid, and moreover, the "quotient category" $C/\sim_S$ is well defined and is in fact a group (say $G$). So exemplary construction (that is opposite to quotient construction) of unique groupoid of $n$ objects over $G$ could be: (1) take full directed graph over $n$ vertices (2) "attach" $G$ to one vertex (3) take quotient of free category over equations deduced from $G$.
To sum up; even if all of this makes sense, I'm not sure if reverse of implication [$^1$] holds: that each finite groupoid has web.
Is "C is groupoid iff it has web" true in finite case? Is it true in general? Are groupoids represented by their "underlying group" and cardinality of object-set?

Comment: A groupoid (the definition that I know) is a category where every morphism is an isomorphism. This doesn't mean that there is a morphism between any two objects. A general groupoid would be a disjoint union of  "trivial" groupoids you have in mind.

Comment: Any groupoid is, up to equivalence, determined by a family of automorphism groups (indexed by the objects in one of its skeletons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct (for connected groupoids). More generally the classification of arbitrary groupoids up to isomorphism (not equivalence) is the following: every groupoid is uniquely a disjoint union of connected groupoids (up to permutation), and the isomorphism type of a connected groupoid $X$ is determined by the pair $(X_0, \pi_1(X))$ of the isomorphism type of its set of objects and the isomorphism type of the automorphism group of any of its objects.

Comment: Thank you. One of my ideas about connected groupoids was if there exists choice of one morphism from each homset, so that resulting diagram would commute, thus being closed under composition. But as you confirmed, that groupoids have such simple structure I guess it is always possible.

Comment: @Przemek: yes, it's always possible. You just start with an object and then arbitrarily pick a morphism (necessarily an isomorphism) from that object to every other object (strictly speaking we need the axiom of choice to do this).